# Show only requested packages (apt, apt-get, dpkg) in terminal (Ubuntu)

Tags: terminal, apt, apt-get, dpkg

Is there a way to list out only "user-requested" installs in terminal on Ubuntu. Not all packages, only the ones that were specifically installed by a/the user.